# Local service or remote service?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have a background Service which must run permanently. The service just has to interact with my Activity.

1. How to i check on activity resume if the service is still running? Is there a better possibility than a static variable in the service class?
2. Is it of advantage to use a remote service in a separate process(to extend service life time) so that when the activity process gets killed the service is still alive?

Comment: ´adb bugreport´ told me that my service crashed too much and was destroyed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have a background service which must
>   run permanently.

[This is not possible](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/). The user or Android will kill off your service at some point. Please reconsider your architecture.

> How to i check on activity resume if
>   the service is still running?

Generally, you don't.

> Is there a better possibility than a static variable in the service class?

That will not work if the user or Android kills off your service.

> Is it of advantage to use a remote
>   service in a separate process(to
>   extend service life time) so that when
>   the activity process gets killed the
>   service is still alive?

A remote service has nothing to do with whether the service runs after activities are destroyed. If you call `startService()`, the service will run, independent of any activities, until:

- you call `stopService()` from an activity
- the service calls `stopSelf()`
- Android terminates the service
- the user terminates the service via the Settings application
- the user terminates the service via a "task killer" (Android 2.1 and earlier, at least)

Comment: and what it want the user to inform the activity on reappearance if the background service is still doing its job?

Comment: @Snej: I do not understand your question, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was a little bit messed up until I realized it.   The question was how to determine when the user relaunches the application whether the background service is still running or has been killed. 
By Macarse's answer an Intent can be thrown at the service. But how do can I find out whether the service was restarted or is still running?

Comment: Finally, I ended up using the suggestion made by hackbod on http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8c4bd731681b8331/bf3ae8ef79cad75d

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to send images in background and show user progress of particular uploading in listview row, i mean to say http communication using service and also notify user on UI then i should use foreground service right? is Remote service needed for this task? Images will be around 10-15 not more than that.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to know if the Service is running?
If you need something from it, just throw an `Intent` and if it's not running it will start by the intent.

In relation with the second question:

Your service will not "die" when your Activity closes.

Comment: I want to know it because the application is logging gps data and it's crucial to log permanently. So i want to let the user know through the activity if it stopped logging because of an exception or killed service.

Comment: I have the same concern as Snej.

Comment: @Sney: This is a hack, but you can try sending `Broadcasts` from the service to let everyone know you are alive.

Answer (score 3):

Start the service in `startforeground()`. It will increase the timespan of the service.